# Get the Property of an item from a ReferenceField type in Sitecore JSS (react)

Tags: jss, graphql

I am currently working on a Sitecore JSS in which I am using GraphQL to retrieve data in Sitecore.

I have field named ArticleTag in my context item which is a (Droptree)

Sitecore GraphQL query:

```
 query{
      contextItem: item(path: "{22C1A19D-CEE3-5E4E-ADB5-373A0E225C91}") {
       id
       path
       ...on AppRoute {
        articleTag{
         targetItem{
           id
           name
          }
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Results of the above query will render for the articleTag:

```
      "articleTag": {
        "targetItem": {
          "id": "726DE02ED0BA57CF8A2A9717E9FBA25D",
          "name": "Manual"
        }
      },
```

my code snippet to retrieve the value from the API to the React Component does not render the value:

```
const { contextItem } = graphQLResult;

<Text field={contextItem.articleTag.targetItem.name} />
```

Is there a way on how I can correctly get the property targetItem name/id of that ReferenceField in the ArticleTag field in my mapping in JSS? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Integrated (https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/graphql/integrated-graphql) or Connected (https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/graphql/connected-graphql) queries?

Comment: I am using Connected mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to easily use the field value in a `<Text />` field helper component, you will need to adjust your query a bit:

```
query {
  contextItem: item(path: "{22C1A19D-CEE3-5E4E-ADB5-373A0E225C91}") {
    id
    path
    ...on AppRoute {
      articleTag {
        jss
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result of the query will give you something like this for the `articleTag` field:

```
"articleTag": {
  "jss": {
    "id": "5f705809-5366-505e-999d-f7c6ce48ef3e",
    "url": "/path/to/referenced/item",
    "fields": {
      "Manual": {
        "value": "This is some text in the Manual field from the item that is referenced by the Article Tag field"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: in Experience Editor, the result will also contain an `"editable"` property/value, e.g.

```
"Manual": {
  "value": "This is some text in the Manual field from the item that is referenced by the Article Tag field",
  "editable": "[Experience Editor markup goes here]"
}
```

Then you would pass the `jss.fields.Manual` property to the field helper component, e.g.

```
const { contextItem } = graphQLResult;

<Text field={contextItem.articleTag.jss.fields.Manual} />
```

The `jss` property is a JSON blob that contains the field value as rendered by Layout Service/JSS and is for use in JSS field helper components.

Alternatively, you don't *have* to use the JSS field helper components. If you just need the `articleTag.targetItem.fields.Manual` value to display as text in your component, you can certainly do that.

```
query {
  contextItem: item(path: "{22C1A19D-CEE3-5E4E-ADB5-373A0E225C91}") {
    id
    path
    ...on AppRoute {
      articleTag {
        targetItem {
          Manual: field(name:"Manual"){
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result of the query will give you something like this for the `articleTag` field:

```
"articleTag": {
  "targetItem": {
    "Manual": {
      "value": "This is some text in the Manual field from the item that is referenced by the Article Tag field"
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
const { contextItem } = graphQLResult;

<div>
  Name: {contextItem.articleTag.targetItem.Manual.value}
</div>
```

However, that value will not be editable in Experience Editor. If you need the field/value to be editable, you should use the value from the `jss` property.

The sample apps have good examples of this in the `GraphQL-ConnectedDemo` component and query. The links below are to the React sample, but the Vue and Angular samples have similar.

Query: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/samples/react/src/components/GraphQL-ConnectedDemo/query.graphql

Component: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/samples/react/src/components/GraphQL-ConnectedDemo/index.js

Comment: Hi Adam thanks for the response. I have tried to use the "jss" (<Text field={contextItem.articleTag.jss.fields.Manual} />) just like what was described but it doesn't render anything on my end. I did try to use the targetItem but it is also returning an undefined error.